# How to generate load testing response time in minutes?

Tags: jmeter

Anybody please let me know, how to get the response time of each transaction in seconds/minutes/hrs not by milliseconds ?

How to configure the test plan for each transactions separately in jmeter?
for example, transaction : load task, transaction : save task,
transaction : login and transaction : sign out.

in seconds/minutes/hrs ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible on "per transaction" basis but it's something that you configure globally.

Looking into *jmeter.properties* file in /bin folder of JMeter installation:

```
# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) JavaDoc for possible values.

You can specify format required by uncommenting and altering `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` property as follows:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
```

Or specify it as JMeter startup script parameter as:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/logfile.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on how to make use of different JMeter properties.